# Nginx multiple root redirect issue

Tags: redirect, nginx, location

I've the following configuration which works well:

```
root /var/www/en;
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /admin {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php;
}

location ~ \.php(/|\?|$) {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param COCKPIT_URL_REWRITE On;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

This redirects all requests to index.php and to admin/index.php for the admin backend.
Now I need to put a copy of the website in a different language to subdirectory having the same redirect rules for the subdirectory. This is actually a separate project with a separate root folder. I'm doing it the following way:

```
location ~ ^/de {
   root /var/www/de;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /de/index.php?$args;
}


location ~ ^/de/admin {
   root /var/www/de;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /de/admin/index.phpd;
}
```

However, this leads to the following nginx error:

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/de/index.php"
```

How this could be fixed?

Thanks ;)

UPDATE:

I managed to get static files working by changing `root` to `alias`. So, now I can access static files site.com/de/test.txt. However, when I try to access site.com/de/ php handler is not working and browser tries to download the php file. I put php handler inside the new location block but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
location ~ \.php(/|\?|$) {

  location /de {
     root /var/www/de;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /de/index.php?$args;
  }

  location /de/admin {
     root /var/www/de;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /de/admin/index.php;
  }

  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param COCKPIT_URL_REWRITE On;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working. Nginx just fails to start. Besides, you're adding this inside the php location. So, static files won't be working anyway.

Comment: I guess this is something to do with the locations matching order. I read the documention, tried some variants but have not found out the solution. I would appreciate if you look in the issue further. Thanks in advance.